# How does one determine runway orientation without a local wind rose?

Tags: weather, airport-design

We are planning to establish new airport, but then we have no wind rose analysis of the location.

How can we predict what's the right orientation for the runway that satisfies the 95.

Comment: If the surrounding terrain is flat then a nearby wind rose analysis could suffice.

Comment: Well, without wind-rose analysis you don't even know what the criteria is, do you?

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, you could also try [earthscience.SE](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/). Your question is basically "how can I determine the prevailing winds in a given location?", which isn't only relevant to aviation.

Comment: Build it 90 degrees from the next closest runway. Murphy's law will then guarantee that both runways always have a 45 degree crosswind.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you are not bound by local topography and thus can build the runway in, theoretically any direction you like, there are a few things you can do. First, you could set up a [small weather station and record some data](https://www.weathershack.com/listing/complete-home-weather-stations.html). You could then use this data to determine your direction. You can also use [a site like this one](https://www.wunderground.com/) to see the historical wind/weather data in the area. This will help you get an idea of the prevailing winds at near by.